# The model $\langle \Bbb N,\epsilon \rangle$ does not satisfy the axiom of infinity

Tags: set-theory

It is a question from Cori, Lascar, Pelletier's mathematical logic. Chapter 5 exercise 1.

Let $\phi:\Bbb N\to W$ be a bijection, where $W$ is the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb N$. The claim is that $\langle \Bbb N,\epsilon\rangle$ satisfies all the axioms of ZF except for the axiom of infinity, where the relation $\epsilon$ is defined as:

$x\mathrel\epsilon y\Leftrightarrow x\in \phi(y)$

The solution manual says:

If we have $a\in\Bbb N$ such that

$\langle \Bbb N,\epsilon\rangle\vDash f$ is a mapping from $a$ into itself that is injective but not surjective.

We easily see the set $\{(x,y)\in \phi(a)^2: \langle \Bbb N,\epsilon\rangle\vDash y = f(x)\}$ is a mapping from $\phi(a)$ to itself that is injective but not surjective, contradiction because $\phi(a)$ is finite.

I have trouble making sense of the set $\{(x,y)\in \phi(a)^2: \langle \Bbb N,\epsilon\rangle\vDash y = f(x)\}$. Why does it even "type check'' (i.e. why does this set even make sense)? The function $f$ is from $a$ to $a$, whereas the $x$ is in $\phi(a)$, not $a$. Moreover, $f(x)$ is in $a$ by definition of $f$ as well. I suppose the construct of this set aims to restrict the function $f$ to a subset. A restriction of an injection is injective, but how can we conclude it is not surjective to some set?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe it would be less confusing and more "type safe" to consider the model of all finite subsets with the relation $A \epsilon B \iff \phi^{-1}(A) \in B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the cases where the definitions get confusing. $(\Bbb N,\epsilon)$ satisfies, by our assumption, that there is $f\colon a\to a$ which is injective and not surjective.

What does that mean? Well, $a$ is the same object as $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid x\in\phi(a)\}$ in our structure. So $f$ can be "transferred" to a function on $\phi(a)$ given by $g(x)=y$ if and only if $(N,\epsilon)\models f(x)=y$. But since $\phi(a)$ is finite, $g$ cannot be injective and not surjective.

So, we are not restricting $f$ to $\phi(a)$ or anything like that. We assumed to begin with that $f$ was a function on $a$, we "translate" it into a function $g$ defined on $\phi(a)$, but that set is finite, so it is impossible that $g$ is injective and not surjective. So $f$ cannot be injective and not surjective either.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. Since $\phi$ is a bijection, $\phi(a)$ is identified with $a$, but could you please explain why we can have $g(x) = y$ (where $x,y\in \phi(a)$) iff $(N,\epsilon)\vDash f(x) = y$ (where $x,y\in a$)? I am also not sure what do you mean by $a$ is the same object as $\{x\in \Bbb N\mid x\in \phi(a)\}$, the later is not an element in our structure. I think maybe you are saying something like $f:a\to a$ becomes $\phi(f):\phi(a)\to \phi(a)$ in a functorial way, but I do not see how we can do it.

Comment: No, $a$ and $\phi(a)$ are not the same object. But $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid (N,\epsilon)\models x\mathrel{\epsilon}a\}=\{x\in\Bbb N\mid x\in\phi(a)\}$. Now, we define $g$ that way because we have access to the truth in $(\Bbb N,\epsilon)$. Since $f$ was defined on $a$, which externally is the set $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid x\in\phi(a)\}$, that means that $g$ we defined is defined on $\phi(a)$.

Comment: Therefore, $g$ and $f$ are really the same, and $g$ is just the "external version" of $f$ because a function $f:a\to a$ in $(N,\epsilon)$ is just a function $\phi(a)\to \phi(a)$ in the "ambient model" of set theory where $\Bbb N$ sits in? Is that true?

Comment: And the reason is: a relation $R_f$ on $a$ that defines $f$ says $\forall x\epsilon a\exists! y\epsilon  a (R_f(x,y))$. Externally, it is $\forall x\in \phi(a)\exists! y\in \phi( a) (R_f(x,y))$. Hence the function is "really" (i.e. externally) on $\phi(a)$.

Comment: Yes. That is the point, in a nutshell.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation! I get it.